# PHP : Japanese character validation : Why Hiragana characters validated against regular expression of Katakana characters?

Tags: php, regex, validation, utf-8, preg-match

I want to validate whether user's input is in **Full width Katakana** characters or not ?

Here is a set of japanese characters according to categories

http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml

Now look at below code, I am trying to validate, different inputs

`$pattern` contains all full width katakana characters

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        $pattern = "/^([゠ァアィイゥウェエォオカガキギクグケゲコゴサザシジスズセゼソゾタダチヂッツヅテデトドナニヌネノハバパヒビピフブプヘベペホボポマミムメモャヤュユョヨラリルレロヮワヰヱヲンヴヵヶヷヸヹヺ・ーヽヾヿ]+)$/";
        $values = array("ナカ" , 
                        "ね",
                        "PHP",
                        "ナカPHP",
                       );

        foreach ($values as $value){
            echo $value. "  =>  ";
            if(preg_match($pattern, $value)){
                echo "valid";
            }else{
                echo "invalid";
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
```

1st value in `$values` array is valid full width katakana, 2nd is Hiragana, and 3rd and 4th are invalid entries.

I am getting following output.

```
ナカ => valid
ね => valid
PHP => invalid
ナカPHP => invalid
```

Concern is why Hiragana characters validated, this issue exists against many Hiragana characters while need is only **Full width KataKana**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to turn on the unicode modifier.

Comment: `"/^([゠ァアィイゥウェエォオカガキギクグケゲコゴサザシジスズセゼソゾタダチヂッツヅテデトドナニヌネノハバパヒビピフブプヘベペホボポマミムメモャヤュユョヨラリルレロヮワヰヱヲンヴヵヶヷヸヹヺ・ーヽヾヿ]+)$/u";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like i said in my comment, you need to turn on the unicode modifier `u`. And note that when you're dealing with unicode characters, you must need to enable unicode modifier `u`.

```
$pattern = "/^([゠ァアィイゥウェエォオカガキギクグケゲコゴサザシジスズセゼソゾタダチヂッツヅテデトドナニヌネノハバパヒビピフブプヘベペホボポマミムメモャヤュユョヨラリルレロヮワヰヱヲンヴヵヶヷヸヹヺ・ーヽヾヿ]+)$/u";
                                                                                                                                                           ^
```

Answer (score -2):

For my answer. I will define for any text

```
$partten = '/^([\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]+)$/u';
preg_match($partten, $values);
```

Comment: After 1 year of asking the question, I have no desire to test this code, provide information that would verify the desired output of the OP.